# NoMethodError: undefined method `to_gmap4rails' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_xyz_controller>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using gmaps4rails gem to show map on view part.
gmaps4rails '1.5.6'
 
rails 4.0.0
ruby 2.0.0

**Model Action**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_gmappable
 
  def gmaps4rails_address
    address
  end
end
```

**Controller Action**

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    binding.pry
    @locations = Location.all.to_gmaps4rails
  end
end
```

Here its showing

```
**NoMethodError: undefined method `to_gmap4rails'  #<ActiveRecord::Relation::
```

Any response please reply
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 does not load records with "all" anymore.

If you want to load your array of records you should use to_a

```
Location.all.to_a.to_gmaps4rails
```